# Updating last node in a linked list using a mutable pointer to the List

Tags: rust

Hi Guys I'm stuck fighting the borrow checker, it seems it still hasn't 'clicked' for me. Basically I have a linked list and I'm trying to update the last node of the list

This is how the list is defined

```
enum List {
    Empty,
    Head(Option<Box<Node>>),
}

struct Node {
    val : i32,
    next : Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

And this is the implementation for the List

```
impl List {
    fn new() -> Self {
        List::Head(Some(Box::new(Node {
            val: 42,
            next:None,
        })))
    }

    fn IterateTillLast(lhead: &List) {
        let mut counter = 1;
        match lhead {
            List::Empty => println!("Empty List"),
            List::Head(head) => {
                let mut itr = head;
                loop {
                    if  let Some(x) = itr {
                        println!("{counter} -> {}", x.val);
                        if x.next.is_some() {
                            itr = &x.next;
                            counter += 1;
                        } else {
                            println!("Reached the last node");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
 
                // THIS WORKS
                if let Some(last_node) = itr {
                    println!("Last node {}", last_node.val); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fn UpdateLast(lhead: &mut List) {
        match lhead {
            List::Empty => println!("Empty List"),
            List::Head(head) => {
                let mut itr = head;

                loop {
                    if let Some(x) = itr {
                        if x.next.is_some() {
                            itr = &mut x.next;
                        } else {
                            // This is the last node, lets update
                            x.val = 0xff;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                // RUST IS MAD HERE
                if let Some(last_node) = itr {
                    println!("Updated last node to {}", last_node.val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coming from C, having a pointer to the head of the list and updating the pointer to point to the next node is my default thought process but somehow I'm offending the compiler I'm not sure why. Having a mutable reference means I'm not moving the value. Then why is this not working

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `*itr` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:83:24
   |
72 |                     if let Some(x) = itr {
   |                                 - `itr.0` is borrowed here
...
83 |                 if let Some(last_node) = itr {
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        use of borrowed `itr.0`
   |                        borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `itr.0` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:83:29
   |
72 |                     if let Some(x) = itr {
   |                                 - first mutable borrow occurs here
...
83 |                 if let Some(last_node) = itr {
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^
   |                             |
   |                             second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                             first borrow later used here
```

Comment: Rust is particularly not friendly to linked lists. If you are trying to learn Rust or how the borrow checker works, this is not the way to go about it. Here lies only pain and hurt. Pretty much what [this](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) rambling rant says about them and Rust.

Comment: Linked lists is not where you should learn rust. The way we implement linked lists in C violates one-owner from time to time. Don't implement your own linked list use the standard library collections instead

Comment: Is this something which could help change you mind: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Guys its a learning experiment. Not meant for production. I'm just failing to understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: And we are telling you what you are doing wrong. This is a waste of time for you, find some other way to learn about borrow checker.

Comment: I believe this is an instance of [this known bug](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70255). Your code compiles with the experimental Polonius borrow checker that is intended to fix this bug (among others): https://godbolt.org/z/bbGcsWY9h

Comment: THANK YOU Jmb!!! If you want to please submit as answer I will accept :)

Comment: @Tanveer you could've just said I don't know instead of dishing out unwaranted advice about things you clearly know very little about